# How to define custom scala input helper for checkbox

Tags: scala, templates, playframework

I am trying to build an input helper for Play Framework in Scala.

I would like to have my inputs of type `radio` and `checkbox` to be printed differently than the standard `text` or `password` input types ?

Here is my custom helper:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="@elements.id" class="col-lg-2 control-label">@elements.label</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="@elements.id" />
    </div>
</div>
```

But this prints an `text input` instead of `checkbox input`. Which is strange behaviour.

I've read the documentation, but couldn't find anything about it.

Here is how I import this `helper` to `view`:

```
@implicitFieldConstructor = @{ FieldConstructor(generic.views.html.FormHelpers.twitterBootstrapInputSupraClub.render) }
@checkboxFieldConstructor = @{ FieldConstructor(generic.views.html.FormHelpers.twitterBootstrapInputSupraClubCheckbox.render) }
```

And this is how I call helpers to build input (generates inputs) in `view`:

```
@inputText(
    accountRegistrationForm("email"),
    '_label -> "email"
)

@inputPassword(
    accountRegistrationForm("password"),
    '_label -> password
)

@inputRadioGroup(
    accountRegistrationForm("regulationAcceptance"),
    options = Seq("true"->"Yes"),
    '_label -> "I agree with regulation",
    'type -> "radio"
)(handler = checkboxFieldConstructor, implicitly[Lang])
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something here but as far as I can see, you seem to me missing the right input type.

In your helper, try changing `<input type="text"...` to `<input type="radio"...`

You can pass the input type dynamically, too. e.g.

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements, inputType: String)

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="@elements.id" class="col-lg-2 control-label">@elements.label</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="@inputType" class="form-control" id="@elements.id" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

I have something similar to this for radio buttons:

given that my userDetailForm contains canLogOn:

```
"company" -> nonEmptyText,
"canLogon" -> boolean,
"canTrade" -> boolean,
```

I created a function in views: `radioSet(fieldName: String)`

```
@radioSet(fieldName: String) = {
   <label for="@fieldName">Can Logon</label>
   <input name=@fieldName id=@fieldName type="radio" value = "true"  
   @if(userDetailForm(fieldName).value.getOrElse("false").equals("true"))
   {checked}>
}
```

Then I call it when I need it:

```
@radioSet("canLogon")
```

And I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXslf.jpg (sorry I cant post images yet)

Comment: Can You give me an example of `@inputText(accountRegistrationForm("email"), '_label -> "email")` usage with Your example?

Comment: What is your helper called, and how are you calling it?

Comment: Ok. I am asking how you are calling your custom helper as I can only see `@inputText`, `@inputPassword` and `@inputRadioGroup` which are all members of Play's helper package. I can't see how you are calling your custom helper. In the Edit, I have demonstrated what I do when I need a custom helper, which is declaring a new method, and then calling it when it's needed.

Comment: Ok. Now I see. I've added `handler` to post. As You can see I have other approach.